# When is a 2D homogenous potential essentially self-adjoint? What about the potential $V(x,y)=x^4+y^4-\lambda x^2y^2$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics, potential-theory

Suppose I consider the operator
$$
-\Delta+V$$
for some potential $V(x)$ for $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, as the closure of the corresponding operator on smooth compactly supported functions. If I assume that
$$
V(tx,ty)=t^4V(x,y)
$$
are there any criteria that make the operator non self-adjoint? For instance, if I take
$$
V(x,y)=x^4+y^4-\lambda x^2y^2
$$
then for $\lambda\leq 2$ the operator is self-adjoint but what happens for $\lambda>2$? I'm thinking, is there some condition in terms of positivity at $\infty$ in all directions that's equivalent to self adjointness?